# Insert Mutiple Record into Database Using Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a forecast.This forecast has been successfully implemented and i want to run summary report based on the forecast. To achieve this, i had to allow the user to click a button "Summary Report". Upon clicking the button, it will insert the record into the Database and immediately fetch and analyze the data into summary as required. Question now is that the record are much like 1200 records. This records are not inserted into the DB,perhaps because it is too much. But when i reduce the period of the forecast such that the record is like 100, it will insert the data  and analyze it as required. What should i do for the record of says 5000 to be inserted into the Database. Or is there a better way to achieve multiple insertion to the database?
See below the insertion code:

```
if(isset($_POST['exportBtn'])){
        foreach($_POST['sj'] as $key => $value) {
         $eflt = $_POST['sflt'][$key];
         $emodel = $_POST['smodel'][$key];
         $eengine =$_POST['sengine'][$key];
         $eloc = $_POST['sloc'][$key];
         $estye = $_POST['sstye'][$key];
         $ensvr = $_POST['snsvr'][$key];
         $eehd = $_POST['sehd'][$key];
              $inExp = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO table_name(fltno,model,engine,loc,serviceType,nextSvr,usageHr)VALUES('$eflt','$emodel','$eengine','$eloc','$estye','$ensvr','$eehd')");
        }//End for-each loop
```

Comment: how you inserting records can u please provide more details along with code

Comment: @Prateik: if(isset($_POST['exportBtn'])){
        foreach($_POST['sj'] as $key => $value) {
         $eflt = $_POST['sflt'][$key];
         $emodel = $_POST['smodel'][$key];
         $eengine =$_POST['sengine'][$key];
         $eloc = $_POST['sloc'][$key];
         $estye = $_POST['sstye'][$key];
         $ensvr = $_POST['snsvr'][$key];
         $eehd = $_POST['sehd'][$key];
              $inExp = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO table_name(fltno,model,engine,loc,serviceType,nextSvr,usageHr)VALUES('$eflt','$emodel','$eengine','$eloc','$estye','$ensvr','$eehd')");
        }//End foreac

Comment: edit your question and provide code in the proper format so we can understand what exactly you want and what is the current problem.

Comment: Please, why is the question downvoted? Is the question not valid? Is there any solution in SO relating to this or what exactly?

Comment: the information you provided is not enough, you need to provide you database structure and code, the question is lack of explanation https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, see correction above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160690/discussion-between-dave-and-prateik).

Comment: there is one way with which you can just put `set_time_limit(0)` just after starting of `foreach` loop brackets it will take a long time to be inserted into the database but it will work.

Comment: Let me try it now

Comment: I have tried it, but still not inserting

Comment: is there any error or inserting some of the records something like what?

Comment: No error. Like i said, if the record is like 100, it will work and generate summary, but once it is more than that, it will truncate and not insert anything at all, with no message.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $arr = array();
    foreach($_POST['sj'] as $key => $value) {
         $eflt = $_POST['sflt'][$key];
         $emodel = $_POST['smodel'][$key];
         $eengine =$_POST['sengine'][$key];
         $eloc = $_POST['sloc'][$key];
         $estye = $_POST['sstye'][$key];
         $ensvr = $_POST['snsvr'][$key];
         $eehd = $_POST['sehd'][$key];
         array_push($arr,"('$eflt','$emodel','$eengine','$eloc','$estye','$ensvr','$eehd')");
}
$inExp = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO table_name(fltno,model,engine,loc,serviceType,nextSvr,usageHr) VALUES ".implode(',',$arr));
```

Do it with one query. Also you can do it with prepared statements easily..

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I've edited my answer. (added `VALUES` after `INSERT INTO .. ()`)

Comment: Still the same, it only work for record  less or close to 100. Anything above this, is still not working with the code you gave above. Any further assistance?

Comment: problem is in your mysql config file. not in your query. go to mysql folder and change `query_cache_limit` in config file

Comment: What exactly do i need to change in the config file

Comment: my `query_cache_limit1 is 1048576. So what should i do

Comment: can you post me the last error in `mysql/data/mysql_error.log`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160701/discussion-between-dave-and-ramesh-kithsiri-hettiarachchi).

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your database engine to "InnoDB" if its different as it's provide Row level locking that improves data operation faster in table.

Second, instead of inserting one by one row in to MySQL table, prepare string with all rows and insert it in one go as assembling one INSERT statement with multiple rows is much faster in MySQL than one INSERT statement per row.

EX.

```
$arrData = array(); 
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $arrData[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['text']).'", '.$row['id'].')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (text, id) VALUES '.implode(',', $arrData));
```

Above query will insert all data in one go. Also you can divide $arrData variable if you have to insert thousands of data. In my case, I had successfully inserted 4200 data having 10 columns data.

Comment: Where do i change the database engine, as i see that some table have myISAM while oher have InnoDB?

Comment: Please, help me out. how do i prepare the all rows as one string? Then are you saying after get all the rows as one string then i can insert it using foreach loop? Please i need  assistance, as i have not inserted mutiple record as this before into the DB

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = [];
    $allData = [];
    if(isset($_POST['exportBtn'])){
        foreach($_POST['sj'] as $key => $value) {
            $data[] = isset($_POST['sflt'][$key])?$_POST['sflt'][$key]:'';
            $data[] = isset($_POST['smodel'][$key])?$_POST['smodel'][$key]:'';
            $data[] = isset($_POST['sengine'][$key])?$_POST['sengine'][$key]:'';
            $data[] = isset($_POST['sloc'][$key])?$_POST['sloc'][$key]:'';
            $data[] = isset($_POST['sstye'][$key])?$_POST['sstye'][$key]:'';
            $data[] = isset($_POST['snsvr'][$key])?$_POST['snsvr'][$key]:'';
            $data[] = isset($_POST['sehd'][$key])?$_POST['sehd'][$key]:'';
            $allData []= '('.implode(',', $data).')';
       }
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO table_name (fltno,model,engine,loc,serviceType,nextSvr,usageHr) VALUES '.implode(',', $allData));
}
```

Comment: Please add some text, to describe what the code does and why it answers the Q.

Comment: @todary, still not working. Then should it not be concatenated? like $data[] = $_POST['sflt'][$key]; $data[].=$_POST['smodel'][$key];

Comment: it does not work at all. infact, even 10 records can no longer be inserted.

Comment: can i see the output data from $_POST['exportBtn']?

Comment: No output on clicking the exportBtn., once the records exceed 100.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['exportBtn'])){
var_dump($_POST['exportBtn']);
die();
}

Comment: C:\wamp\www\ams\ams\test.php:82:string 'Generate Summary' (length=16)

Comment: i made the edit ,if it do not work please tell me the error

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: try use !empty()